# add/remove [toggle] for menu when click on button by add one word to class using javascript

Tags: html, css, class, menu, toggle

***this button when i click it***

```
<div id="header-nav-container">
            <div id="explore" class="btn btn-clear header-nav">
                <a title="Explore">Explore </a>
            </div>
```

***i want this menu open and click agin close like toggle***

```
 <div id="header-menus">
 <div id="explore-menu" class="header-menu open">
```

[image]

Comment: Please, explain more or post your jquery or jsfiddle

Comment: when class="header-menu" the menu closed but when write class="header-menu open" the menu open >>>>i want know the java script code that can make this >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: click on this button   <div id="explore" class="btn btn-clear header-nav">
                <a title="Explore">Explore </a>
            </div>  the menu open and close (toggle) that doing by class when add *open*  u can understand me?? like add apart (one word ) into class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a title="Explore" onclick="toggleOpen();">Explore </a>

function toggleOpen(){
    if (document.getElementById("explore-menu").className == "header-menu") {
        document.getElementById("explore-menu").className = "header-menu open";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("explore-menu").className = "header-menu";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jQuery toggleClass() or slideToggle().

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">Explore</a>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non odio sit amet tortor lacinia eleifend. Nulla vel felis felis, tempor varius turpis. Curabitur fermentum pulvinar convallis. Donec posuere cursus lectus sit amet bibendum. Nunc ut arcu dolor, lacinia interdum ante. Vestibulum ut neque augue, sit amet vulputate neque. Proin auctor, neque at volutpat accumsan, orci elit iaculis velit, eu dictum ipsum nibh quis lacus.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<a href="#" class="toggle-2">Explore 2</a>
<div class="content-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus non odio sit amet tortor lacinia eleifend. Nulla vel felis felis, tempor varius turpis. Curabitur fermentum pulvinar convallis. Donec posuere cursus lectus sit amet bibendum. Nunc ut arcu dolor, lacinia interdum ante. Vestibulum ut neque augue, sit amet vulputate neque. Proin auctor, neque at volutpat accumsan, orci elit iaculis velit, eu dictum ipsum nibh quis lacus.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display:none;
}
div.open {
    display:block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".toggle").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".content").slideToggle("slow");
    }); 
    jQuery(".toggle-2").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
       jQuery(".content-2").toggleClass("open");
    }); 
});
```

And the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/lddz/p4sh8v1u/

Comment: 2 button no ...on the same e button like this  http://www.instructables.com/  enter on this website and click on explore button will under stand me ..i want this

Comment: @eng.heba, the first example in the fiddle is exactly doing this.

http://jsfiddle.net/lddz/w0039o10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#explore').on({
    click: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').find('#explore-menu').toggleClass('open');
    }

}, '#header-nav-container');
```